# Add custom output to woocommerce cart as a product

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

i made some code for google maps api that calculates the distance from one place to another, but i have a problem with adding the output to the woocommerce price (also displaying it as a product). this is the code i wrote:

The thought was.. that when i press submit, to have a product that would get values from the output of the distance and price, and then add it as a product.

`    function add_fixed_text_product_to_cart( $cost ) {
global $woocommerce;

```
    $product_id = 1825; //the ID of fixed text product
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    if ( $product ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, 1, 0, array(), array( 'cost' => $cost ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_fixed_text_product_to_cart', 'add_fixed_text_product_to_cart' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_fixed_text_product_to_cart', 'add_fixed_text_product_to_cart' );

function add_custom_price_to_cart_item( $cart_object ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        if ( isset( $value['cost'] ) ) {
            $value['data']->set_price( $value['cost'] );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price_to_cart_item', 10, 1 );


function zip_code_input_shortcode()
{
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Enter address" style="text-align: center;">
    <div id="address-dropdown"></div>
    <div id="output">
        <span id="distance_result"></span>
        <br><br>
        <span id="cost_result"></span>
        <br><br>
        <button id="submit_zipcode">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#submit_zipcode').click(function() {
        // Get the calculated cost
        var cost = parseFloat(jQuery('#cost_result').text().split(' ')[1].replace(',', '.'));

        // Add the information to the WooCommerce cart as a fixed text
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: {
                 'action': 'add_fixed_text_product_to_cart',
            'cost': cost
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

});

```
    function initMap() {
        var startingLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(55.84336022202228, 9.835100295423425);

        var input = document.getElementById('address');
        var options = {
            types: ['address'],
            componentRestrictions: { country: 'dk' }
        };
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            var destination = place.formatted_address;
            var destination_lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
            var destination_lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
            var postal_code = "";

            // Get the postal code from the address components
            for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                if (addressType === "postal_code") {
                    postal_code = place.address_components[i].long_name;
                }
            }

            // Check if the postal code is within the range of 1000 to 4999
            if (postal_code >= 999 && postal_code <= 4999) {
                alert("Vi montere desværre ikke varmepumper på Sjælland.");
                return;
            }

            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            service.getDistanceMatrix({
                origins: [startingLocation],
                destinations: [destination],
                travelMode: 'DRIVING',
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            }, function (response, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    var distance_result = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                    var distance_value = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value / 1000;
                    distance_value = distance_value.toFixed(2);

                    if (distance_value <= 25) {
                        var cost = 0;
                    } else {
                        var cost = (distance_value - 25) * 5.95;
                        cost = cost.toFixed(2);
                    }

                    document.getElementById('distance_result').innerHTML = 'Distance: ' + distance_result;
                    document.getElementById('cost_result').innerHTML = 'Cost: ' + cost.toString().replace('.', ',') + ' Danish kroner';

                } else {
                    alert('Error: ' + status);
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>`
```

(i dident include the API for this)

i tried to create some JS for this, but it dident work..

`jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#submit_zipcode').click(function() {
// Get the calculated cost
var cost = parseFloat(jQuery('#cost_result').text().split(' ')[1].replace(',', '.'));

```
    // Add the information to the WooCommerce cart as a fixed text
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {
            'action': 'add_fixed_text_product_to_cart',
            'cost': cost
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

});`